# How to modify checkpoint variables by name in TensorFlow 2 for transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, transfer-learning

Reading from a checkpoint is straightforward in TF2 using `tf.train.list_variables()` and `tf.train.load_variable()` or `tf.train.load_checkpoint()`.

However, I'm not sure how I can do any of the following without having access to the Python trackable objects used to generate the checkpoint:

- Modify a checkpoint's variable by name
- Create a new checkpoint that includes all the existing variables with a few modifications

Using `tf.train.Checkpoint()` to create a new variable is possible but it doesn't support arbitrarily naming variables at the root level. Variable names which have a forward slash are escaped meaning scoped variables need to be specified using explicit nested trackable objects.

Is it possible to simply set the value of a variable using its name?

A minimal example illustrating reading a checkpoint is shown below (uses TF version 2.3.1):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class B(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.c = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.int32)

class A(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = B()

ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(a=A())
ckpt.save('/tmp/ckpt')

print(tf.train.list_variables('/tmp/ckpt-1'))

assert tf.train.load_variable('/tmp/ckpt-1', 'a/b/c/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE') == 1
```

The goal is to be able to write to the variable named `a/b/c/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE`
without having to use the Python object `A()`, instead writing directly to the checkpoint
using a method similar to `tf.train.load_variable()`. An alternative of recreating a new checkpoint with the modifications should also work if that is similarly possible.

Any idea how to achieve any of this?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation it may be easiest to use a nested `dict` structure to replicate the scoping shown in the variable names. Checkpoint variables end with `/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE` and the name of variables can be easily extracted (everything before that).

In the case of the example above, assignment can be performed as below:

```py
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(a=dict(b=dict(c=tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.int32))
ckpt.restore('/tmp/ckpt')

# Access nested `dict` structure under the root value of `ckpt.a`.
ckpt.a['b']['c'] = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)
ckpt.save('/tmp/ckpt')
```